# How do I rotate in edit mode?

Tags: transforms

Is there a way to rotate an object a specific number of degrees if you are in edit mode? When I am in edit mode, I can't find a tool to rotate.
Is there maybe a feature I have to turn on? I just started working with Blender.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Press `R`and enter the desired rotation value. In *Edit Mode* there are no "objects", so there can't be a rotation property panel

Comment: To rotate a specific amount in edit mode use the keyboard  shortcut. For example pressing R 45 will rotate the selected vertices/edges/faces 45 degrees. R X 45 will rotate selected geometry 45 degrees in the X axis only. R shift Y -90 will rotate selected geometry in the Z and X axis minus 90 degrees. Pressing RR will make the rotation take place in the local axis.

Answer (score 2):

In Edit mode, select all vertices using <kbd>A</kbd>, then hit <kbd>R</kbd>, (and possibly <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> to lock the rotation axis - if you hit it twice, it will lock to to local instead of the global axis) and the number of degrees you want to rotate.